# Button for cursor change is not changing

Tags: html, css

**HTML:**

```css
div#cursorCustom {
  background: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.5px;
  border-color: rgba(154,145,145,1.00);
  border-radius: 50px;
}
img.button1 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
img.button2 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
#button:active{
  cursor: url(Cursor1.png);
}
#button2:active{
  cursor: url(Cursor2.png);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="cursorCustom">
    <a href=# id="button"><img src="Cursor1.png" class="Button1"></a>
    <a href=# id="button2"><img src="Cursor2.png" class="Button2"></a>
  </div> 
</body>
```

When I click the 'button' it does not change the cursor to my desired image. Do I have to apply the cursor in a HTML or body selector for it to applied to the entire page?

Comment: did you check properly image path? Please read this article https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/

Comment: Yes and it kind of works I can see it activating but only in the Div cursorCustom I can't see how I can get it to apply to the whole HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. And for it to also work, when the button isn't active, you should toggle an attribute in your body.

```
html[use-my-cursor="1"] {
  cursor: url(Cursor1.png);
}
```

and change it with the following JS:

```
document.documentElement.setAttribute("use-my-cursor", "1");
```

---

Working example:

```js
function setCursor(nr){
  document.documentElement.setAttribute("use-my-cursor", nr);
}
```

```css
html[use-my-cursor="1"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
html[use-my-cursor="2"] {
  cursor: crosshair;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="setCursor(1)">Pointer</button>
<button onclick="setCursor(2)">Crosshair</button>
```

Note that the cursor style may of course still be overridden (e.g. buttons do that).

Comment: Ok thanks I understand but I still can't get it to work I've been looking at some tutorials at DOM but still confused. I have a button which on click runs a function with the DOM code above. Then in my CSS I have your lines yet I am still not seeing any change.

Comment: Works for me. I have added an example. Maybe that will solve your problems.

Comment: btw. you could even use strings in your attribute's value, it doesn't have to be an integer